# use Effect not being called as expected

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to implement a simple file upload drop zone in React:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const  App = () => {
  const [isDropzoneActive, setIsDropzoneActive] = useState(false);
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const [currentChunkIndex, setCurrentChunkIndex] = useState(null);

  const handleDragOver = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDropzoneActive(true);
  };

  const handleDragLeave = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsDropzoneActive(false);
  };

  // Update the files array
  const handleDrop = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setIsDropzoneActive(false);
    // Just overwrite for this simple example
    setFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
  };

  // Monitor the files array
  useEffect(() => {
    if (files.length > 0) {
      console.log('got a file');

      setCurrentChunkIndex(0);
    }
  }, [files]);

  // Monitor the chunk index
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentChunkIndex !== null) {
      readAndUploadCurrentChunk();
    }
  }, [currentChunkIndex]);

  const readAndUploadCurrentChunk = () => {
    // Implement later
  };

  return (
    <div
      onDragOver={handleDragOver}
      onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
      onDrop={handleDrop}
      className={"dropzone" + (isDropzoneActive ? " active" : "")}
    >
        {files.length > 0 ? 'Uploading' : 'Drop your files here'}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However it seems that the effect that monitors `[currentChunkIndex]` is not being called correctly. I have attempted to drag files into the drop zone, one by one. `[files]` effect it called correctly each time but the effect on `[currentChunkIndex]` doesn't get called. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `setCurrentChunkIndex(0);` is this right?

Comment: when you use like this, you can get only once rewrite.

Comment: `setCurrentChunkIndex(0);` - setting `currentChunkIndex` to 0 won't trigger the effect that depends on it again and again because the value isn't changing. You could use an object which would be different each time, hence the effect will be triggered.

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    if (currentChunkIndex !== null) {
      readAndUploadCurrentChunk();
    }
  }, [currentChunkIndex]);` this code will be work when changing currentChunkIndex

Comment: Also at that time, all page reload again. So you can't reload page if you use setCurrentChunkIndex(0);

Answer (score 0):

`currentChunkIndex` changes from `null` to `0`, you set it only to `0`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (files.length > 0) {
      console.log('got a file');

      setCurrentChunkIndex(files.length);
    }
  }, [files]);
```